# CSS centering not working with margin auto and overflow hidden

Tags: css, positioning, centering

I've noticed that if I view the page at wider resolution, the content of a section gets aligned to the right, instead of centered.

I use

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 998px;
overflow: hidden;
```

It seems to have this bug, at least in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. I tried disabling `overflow: hidden` and it gets rid of the bug, but messes up my floats inside the content.

You can see an example at the page live here:
http://autouncle.dk/da/brugte-biler/Kia or http://autouncle.dk/da/brugte-biler/Ford (you have to view it at at least 1500px widescreen to see the bug).

Any ideas on what can cause this bug and what are possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the reason of the problem: this is due to the `page-title` element of your header:

`#header-outer` element contains some floated elements but you forgot a clearing, so the offset left of the main section of your site starts where the `page-title` ends. (*you can verify this by hiding `page-title` element — when you set `display: none` the page is correctly centered*)

[image]

So adding

```
body#basic_page #header-outer {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

you solve the problem

As a sidenote strongly avoid to put empty div only for clearing purposes: there're cleaner methods that don't require extra markup, like easyclearing

Comment: @Calderan, thanks for the answer, it seems that that is the culprit. However, hiding overflow on the #header-outer or inner is going to mess with the Facebook buttons, as they require the overflow visible to display the overlays.

Comment: I chose to leave the overflow properties as they are and make the margin 0 of the #page-title element, which was causing the float problems. Thanks for the in-depth explanation of what goes on. Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is removing `overflow: hidden`

To fix the float bug on the second example you gave try to use 100% of the width:

```
body#basic_page.brands_controller #content .text_info {
   overflow: hidden;
   font-size: 12px;
   width: 100%; /* new rule */
}
```

Comment: This is working, do you know why? Could it be same reason from @Calderan 's answer, that there are uncleared floats from the #header-inner div?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you provided a valid solution, but @Calderan 's answer led me to a more unobtrusive solution. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
overflow:hidden
```

from `div#content` and put its contents in an extra `<div>`  in it which has

```
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
```

This resolves the problem for me.